# How to send large DataFrame column as list of values to a Function efficiently

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find a statistic (Gini Coefficient) on a `DataFrame` column in which I need to pass all the values of a particular column to function in order to calculate the statistic (Gini Coefficient).

Here, the statistic function expects the “list of values” and return the integer.
In order to gather the list of values from a DataFrame column, I tried below 2 approaches.

Approach 1:

1. Select the column from DataFrame.
2. Covert it to RDD.
3. Map each value to (1,value)
4. groupByKey to aggregate all values.
5. Send the aggregated values to statistic function to calculate the statistic.

Approach 2:

1. Select the column from DataFrame.
2. Covert it to RDD.
3. Perform collect action to aggregate values.
4. Send the aggregated values to statistic function to calculate the statistic.

But both the approaches seem to be working very slow.

Could you please share suggestion or any other way to do it efficiently.

Regards,
Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

If data is sorted and does not have negative nor zeros, you could calculate Gini Coefficient using the third formula described in this page:

http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#nonparametric_methods/gini.htm

An implementation in Python is available at https://github.com/oliviaguest/gini.

It is esasy to compute the sums using dataframe's `df.groupBy().sum()` operation.